# *ls* font differences between files and folders with "--color" option

Tags: terminal, ls, fonts, unicode, coreutils

I have recently switched to **urxvt** from **xterm** for better unicode support and it does much better as to the font fallback.

However I find an interesting issue: *names* of `files` and `folders` are rendered differently. Below is a screenshot that illustrates this.

[image]

<strike>And here is the related settings in `~/.Xresources`</strike>

```
#define my_dejavu          DejaVuSansMono:size=13
#define my_monaco          Monaco:autohint=true:pixelsize=16:size=12
#define my_wqyHei          WenQuanYiMicroHei:size=13
URxvt.font: xft:my_monaco,xft:my_dejavu,xft:my_wqyHei
```

As you can see, the font of 日记 in "`my日记/`" is different from that of "`my日记.txt`"; while at the same time it seems that the font in "`my日记/`" is stil not "my_wqyHei", but seems another font (sorry I cannot recognize that).

<strike>How can it be this? Can I make the folders font fallbacked like regular files with additional settings?</strike>

#### update

As @wurtel mentioned, this issue has NOTHING to do with `urxvt`, but `ls`: in my case `l` is an alias of `ls -F --color=auto` and whenever I use `ls` with *color* this font issue appears.

Why? And how to resolve this?

Comment: Your terminal emulator can't care less whether some text is a file name or a directory name. Your `ls` is colorizing its output and that is apparently influencing the font choice. Perhaps it's using some codes that do more than just change the color.

Comment: @wurtel YES! It seems the issue of `ls`. The `l` in my case is an alias of `ls -F --color=auto` and I find that the font issue appears when using `--color[=WHEN]` with `always` or `auto`(for stdout). Can you please write as the answer and if better provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this problem because `ls` is colorizing its output, and directories are probably being displayed with the `bold` attribute on. However it seems that your chosen font doesn't have a bold variant, and another font is substituted in an attempt to simulate the bold effect. This what you are seeing.

You can modify the `LS_COLORS` environment variable which tells `ls` how to colorize various types of directory entries; usually the `dircolors` command is used to initialize its value, so you mway want to investigate that.